# Can't add subview to bottom of scrollView

Tags: swift, scrollview

So, i'm trying to add a button to bottom of the scrollView but position of the button not as expected, the button's position at the top of the scrollView when i scroll to top, here's my code :

```
    lazy var scrollView : UIScrollView = {
    let scrollV = UIScrollView()
    scrollV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollV.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    scrollV.delegate = self
    scrollV.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    return scrollV
}()
```

in viewDidLoad :

```
       view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topBar.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 1000)
```

finally, I add the button to the scrollView :

```
    scrollView.addSubview(myButton)
    myButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    myButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    myButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    myButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```

Comment: Did you also set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` on `myButton`?

Comment: yes, I did. by the way, I also set topAnchor constraints for it then it's works, I don't know why...

Comment: Ah, I think that might have to do with undefined nature of a scrollview's `contentSize`. If the `contentSize` is unknown, you'll need to set the `topAnchor` as well.